# Changing functionality in react-select

Tags: html, reactjs

I changed my html select to react select. On changing, the following functionality disappeared:

1. When you press some key while focused on html-select list, the option starting with it gets selected and displayed.
2. pressing up-down arrow in opened list, the option gets displayed too.

Can anyone tell me the solution?

Comment: I don't want to change react-select to react-dropdown-select or again in html-select

Comment: I don't know what you mean [react-select](https://react-select.com/home) already works as you describe.

Comment: please share your code and try to be more elaborative

Comment: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/react) or any other live demo will be even greater